# How to change Azure webapp service from calling hostingstart.html to different html

Tags: node.js, azure-web-app-service, office-addins, excel-addins

I'm having a problem running an Azure hosted Excel web addin and hope someone can help. This is what I have done so far:

1. I successfully created an Azure webapp which I can see in a browser and is running default code from the hostingstart.html script.
2. In VS2019, I created an Excel Addin project with some basic code. The project for this starts from the Home.html script that VS2019 automatically generates. I updated the xml manifest file to point to the web app URL that I created in step 1.
3. I downloaded the xxx.PublishSettings file from Azure and used this in VS2019 to publish my application to my Azure web app.
4. If I browse the wwwroot folder in Azure, I can see all the files published by VS2019 so I know the publish action worked correctly.
5. Using the local xml manifest file, I added the addin in Excel online. When I open the addin task pane from the Excel ribbon, I see the message "Cannot get /Home.html".
6. I'm suspecting that the addin is failing because the Azure webapp is starting from hostingstart.html instead of Home.html.

This leads to my question. Should I be changing Azure somehow to start from the project's Home.html script or should the VS project be changed to run from hostingstart.html?

Thanks in advance for any help with this.

This is the screenshot of what happens when I publish the app from VS2019:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Make sure you can open `https://sitename.azurewebsites.net/Home.html`.

Then I think there is no need to entangle the issue of the start page. Because in the code `<SourceLocation DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Home.html" />` has defined this path.

## If you can't access it, then there must be a bug in this excel web addin for vs2019, you can raise a support to confirm.

**You don't need to do any changes in your code. You just need to modify `Default document` in portal.**

Like below, delete all default page, and create `Home.html`.

[image]

Then you can access your web site.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. I've just checked the portal and for my app, I don't have that heading on the configuration page. I can only see "Application settings", "General settings" and "Path mappings".

Comment: @Marsineip Open your portal, find `Settings`->`Configuration`->the third one ,`Default document`.

Comment: @Marsineip Pls click `Save` when you change that. And access the site, you  maybe need clear cache.

Comment: Hi Jason, I've just worked out what I can't find the settings. Default documents are only available for Windows machines and not Linux machines: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/80878/default-documents-configuration-not-available-in-a.html

Comment: @Marsineip Pls wait, I will give you another method.

Comment: @Marsineip Do you use vs2019 to publish your website?

Comment: @Marsineip I will update my answer, and show me default project, when deploy it , no linux option.

Comment: @Marsineip Can a screenshot of the publishing process be shared with us?

Comment: @Marsineip Okey.

Comment: I've just added the screenshot to the bottom of my original post.

Comment: @Marsineip Can you use [screentogif](https://www.screentogif.com/) to show the progress of deploy, like me.

Comment: @Marsineip Mine is the Enterprise Edition 2019, so it’s weird not to see the same options as you.

Comment: I've just added gif of the publish process I see in my VS2019.

Comment: @Marsineip Pls create a new .publish file by click new, I want to see linux options.

Comment: @Marsineip I will search and give you answer later, pls wait 2 hours.

Comment: Ah, if I try to create a new publish file, I don't have any Linux options at all. I only have "Azure App Service (Windows)", "Azure Container Registry" and "Azure Virtual Machine".

Comment: @Marsineip It should not be supported under Linux. But why you can choose linux for the first time I don't know, it may be a bug of vs2019.

Comment: @Marsineip There is no Microsoft Office under Linux, only Libra Office and other third-party software. I believe you should know these.

Comment: @Marsineip Currently you can create a webapp, then I want to know how to directly access Home.html. If you can access it directly, don’t worry about the default start page. Use the path `https://sitename.azurewebsites.net/Home.html` The visit is also very good. If it does not work, it is recommended to publish it under windows.

Comment: @Marsineip If you still have doubts, it is recommended to raise a support ticket on the portal.

Comment: Got it, thanks so much for your help with this. I'll recreate my web app for Windows and not Linux. I should then be able to set the default document. Thanks so much for your help with this.

Comment: Thank you so much. I thought I was doing something wrong. The entire deafult documents was blank so I couldn't find any documents.